# HotSpot (WiFi Access Point) in android

Tags: android, wifi, access-point, ssid

Can someone please help me in launching the activity for "WiFi Access Point". I am able to turn ON the hotspot from code but not able to fetch the name of the network or launch the required activity.

I have tried the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings.wifi", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiApDialog");
cxt.startActivity(intent);
```

Other than this I would also like to fetch HotSpot username & password. The app I am developing is more similar to FoxFi.

Comment: same problem here in Android M.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have no any public intent for it.

But you can open the Wireless & Networks > More ... by using this intent:

```
android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, yes I have tried the above code and it works. But I would like to launch 'wifi access-point' screen straightaway.

Answer (score 0):

try like this this is working for me useing direct open your activity class

```
Activity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```